# mysql - cannot setup root password after install

Tags: mysql

I installed mysql using homebrew (mysql 5.7.13 w/ OSX 10.11.3).  It launches without a problem.  However when I attempt to run "mysql_secure_installation" to secure it, I enter a password for root and get:

Error: Plugin '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B' is not loaded

I get the same message when I try to run mysql -uroot

If I run "mysql" by istself I get the mysql prompt.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling a few times with the same results.

Comment: You mentioned trying to uninstall. Tables and such stored in `/usr/local/var/mysql` would probably not be removed.

Comment: deleting /usr/local/var/mysql then brew uninstall then brew install solved my problem - thanks!  The link you provided didn't contain this solution.